# AddOpenIdConnect with manual Configuration - SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, identityserver4, openid-connect, identitymodel

**Existing Systems**

We are using Identity Server 4 to provide single sign on feature with Google, Azure, or other External providers without any problem.  All we have to do is add client details and authority url or disco url (eg. `.well-known/openid-configuration`) and everything works as expected.

**Scenario**

One of our external Identity Provider said that they cannot provide the public Discovery Document url and they made it private only internally.  Then they provided as the Json file (which contains the exact json texts provided by that url).  So, we are trying to use the values in that json file to set all these endpoint urls and settings manually by using `AddOpenIdConnect` and `OpenIdConnectConfiguration`.

It correctly redirects to the external provider for Authorize requests and we can signin in the external system.  But when the request comes back to our Idsrv4, it couldn't validate the `id_token`.  We are getting `SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException`.  We did try to set the `JwksUri` but, still no luck.

I managed to replicate the same behaviour by using Demo Identity server and please see the following:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("manualidsrv", "IdentityServer Manual", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io/";
                options.ClientId = "login";
                options.ResponseType = "id_token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
                {
                    Issuer = "https://demo.identityserver.io",
                    JwksUri = "https://demo.identityserver.io/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
                    AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/authorize",
                    TokenEndpoint = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token",
                    UserInfoEndpoint = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/userinfo",
                    EndSessionEndpoint = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/endsession",
                    ResponseTypesSupported =
                    {
                        "code",
                        "token",
                        "id_token",
                        "id_token token",
                        "code id_token",
                        "code token",
                        "code id_token token"
                    },
                    GrantTypesSupported = { 
                        "authorization_code",
                        "client_credentials",
                        "refresh_token",
                        "implicit",
                        "password",
                        "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
                    },
                    ResponseModesSupported =
                    {
                        "form_post",
                        "query",
                        "fragment"
                    },
                    IdTokenSigningAlgValuesSupported = { "RS256" },
                    
            };
```

The error we are getting is

```
SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys:
kid: '3BA75FA392E4DAFAC2737B5B4644AA85',
token: '{"alg":"RS256","kid":"3BA75FA392E4DAFAC2737B5B4644AA85","typ":"JWT"}.{"nbf":1596656241,"exp":1596656541,"iss":"https://demo.identityserver.io","aud":"login","nonce":"637322530390217907.xxx","iat":1596656241,"s_hash":"exiANrEFoXVDwA5BK1mGTg","sid":"D90FD8D4FA73AD590E3C53155375EA49","sub":"1","auth_time":1596652196,"idp":"local","name":"Alice Smith","given_name":"Alice","family_name":"Smith","email":"AliceSmith@email.com","email_verified":true,"website":"http://alice.com","amr":["pwd"]}'.
```

I tried to check the jwksUri: https://demo.identityserver.io/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks and I can see the correct kid '3BA75FA392E4DAFAC2737B5B4644AA85' there.

So, it seems to me that Idsrv4 is not loading these keys correctly if we set the Configuration manually.

There are some suggestion to load SigningKeys manually by using `ConfigurationManager` like the following:

```
new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>($"DiscoveryEndpointUrl", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
```

However, since we don't have access to that endpoint url, it doesn't work for us.

Is there anyway to force Idsrv to load keys from jwksUri or provide the keys manually?

Could you please suggest to solve this signing key exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is perhaps to put the Discovery Document from the provider in a JSON document and just have it included in your IdentityServer as a static resource?. And then just add a link to that static endpoint in your configuration?

I doubt IdentityServer care if that document is hosted locally or not.

Comment: Yes, at the moment, I did it like that.  Thanks for your answer and I feel more confidence  now about doing that way.

Comment: I managed to make it work by forcing Idsrv to load signing keys by using `TokenValidationParameters`.  But I don't use it for the production.  It's too much custom codes and maintenance overhead.

If you are interested, you can see the implementation here:

https://github.com/ttcg/OAuthTest/blob/2628dc0ee082cca99fd28ba9cdf9f4a58a28ed67/OAuthTest/OAuthTest.IDP/Startup.cs#L122

Comment: Looked at your code one one feedback is to do a options.Scope.Clear(); before you add your scopes. Some of those scopes are already added by default by the handler itself.